# idl histogram with y-axis in logarithmic scale

Tags: histogram

Is it possible to make in idl an histogram with logarithmic scale in the y-axis? I know it is possible to make logarithmic bins, but I'd like to have log scale in y-axis and linear in x-axis. Gnuplot can do it but it is not very rich in options.